# Can't downvote after taking back

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I was able to downvote an answer, and then unable to change it immediately after.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/i-was-able-to-downvote-an-answer-and-then-unable-to-change-it-immediately-after)
>   [Isn’t the “vote too old to be changed” a little too eager?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/isnt-the-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-a-little-too-eager)

I read an answer and started to downvote. I took it back 10 seconds later. 5 minutes later I decided it really did deserve a downvote, but then I was unable to do so. I get the message "Vote too old to be changed, unless the answer is changed".

Why am I unable to downvote?

Comment: Dupe it baby: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/i-was-able-to-downvote-an-answer-and-then-unable-to-change-it-immediately-after

Comment: Happens to me too all the time.  Unintuitive in its current form.